# Array updater with procedures

Tags: c#

I need to make my button check if the user has:

- entered text into the position textbox
- entered text into the name textbox

if nothing has been entered then it displays an error message box and exits the procedure.

also it needs to call my insertIntoArrayist() procedure and pass the values to it and insert the new value into the array list.
and then call my populateActors() one.

Here is what i have so far:

```
public void ()
{
  *snip*
}
```

Pretty sure at the moment it would add the name, but not into the correct position.. for example if i want to add a name "Bob Marley" into position "1" it needs to go into the top of the array.
There may also be some other errors with the code, so please if you see any let me know! All tips are appreciated :)

Comment: I can see all kinds of problems, but you need to analyze what's going on for yourself instead of expecting everyone to do your work for you. When you run this program (assuming it compiles), does it give you the output you expect?

Comment: Im not expecting people to answer for me, just tips on what seems wrong and i can go back and edit it myself, or hints as to what way i should go about it.. instead of how i am doing it.

Answer (score 1):

That do-while loop in your button click handler is a big problem!

```
//This button needs to give the error if the name or position in the array are left blank//
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // BIG PROBLEM HERE!!!!
    do
    {
        string message = "Invalid Name or Position entered.";
        MessageBox.Show(message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
    while (int.Parse(txtPosition.Text == null));

    InsertIntoArrayList(actName, posNum);
    PopulateActors();
}
```

When the button is first clicked, if the `int.Parse(txtPosition.Text == null)` condition is not met, a message box will be shown repeatedly without giving the user an opportunity to fix the error.

Try this instead:

```
//This button needs to give the error if the name or position in the array are left blank//
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (int.Parse(txtPosition.Text == null)) {
        MessageBox.Show(message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    } else {
        InsertIntoArrayList(actName, posNum);
        PopulateActors();
    }
}
```

This instead checks the condition each time the button is clicked, giving the user the opportunity to fix the issue.

Your array insertion code looks fine to me.

Comment: Yeah when i tested it originally that was the problem, it kept giving me the error. So the if/else seems more appropriate, thanks.